# Identify a Call of Cthulhu scenario where players start with a blank character sheet

Tags: product-identification, call-of-cthulhu

I recall reading about a published *Call of Cthulhu* scenario which had the following premise:

- The characters started in an area where they were the only people around
- A dead body was in front of them and one of the characters was eating a tongue (less sure on this point)
- All characters had amnesia and could not remember their past or how they got there
- The players all started out with blank character sheets

The idea was that without a past, the characters had to find out more about themselves and would fill in the character sheet as they went along and discovered their abilities. I first heard about this scenario at least five years ago. I asked a Chaosium employee about this adventure and they seemed to recall that it existed, but didn't know the name or what book it came from.

What scenario was this, and what version of *Call of Cthulhu* was it made for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That sounds very much like *In Media Res* ([sic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_medias_res)) by John Tynes. It was published in *The Unspeakable Oath 10* in 1993 and was republished in *The Resurrected III – Out of the Vault* (2002). It was probably made for whatever was the current version of Cthulhu in 1993, but (like any scenario) it should be directly compatible with any Cthulhu version before 7.

As to your points (possible spoilers ahead):

- One of the characters starts the game with somebody else’s tongue in his mouth (not necessarily eating it) and without his own.
- All characters start the game without knowing who they are.
- The characters start in a house, where they are the only persons.
- The characters do not start with blank character sheets, but there is little useful information on their character sheets.

A bit about the premise (if it is helping):

> The characters are prison inmates who were possessed by some avatar of Nyarlathotep, escaped, and murdered a few people. They have just performed a ritual (Opening of the Ways) which blew away their memories. At this point, the scenario starts.